# Bootstrap 3 navbar dropdowns are cutted of

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a navbar:

[image: Navbar]

which contains several menu points with dropdowns. To avoid line breaks before breaking into the md-viewpoint I planned to make this navbar scrollable on the x-axis.

This is working withtout any problems with the following code:

```
<div class="header-container-nav-master hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<ul class="header-navigator container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
 <li class="dropdown"><div class="dropdown show">
    <a href="..." class="nav-sub dropdown-toggle" data-ref="71" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Item</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <ul>
    <li><strong>Subheading</strong></li>
    <li class="brandsofcat"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul></div>
  </div>
</li>
....
<li>...</li>
....
 </div>
</ul>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.header-container-nav-master {
 width: 100%;
 background-color:#fff;
 height:52px;
 padding:0px 18px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: visible;}

 .header-container-nav-master ul {
 height:100%;
 padding:0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;}

 .header-container-nav-master ul li {
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 0.75px;
 padding-right: 22px;
 color: #1f1f1f!important;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style:none;}
```

As shown in the example pic I have the problem that the dropdowns are cut off from the following container.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is the `overflow-x: scroll;` that you have in your CSS.

Took the code you gave here and put it into codepen.

Take a look at that it and see the comments in the CSS block: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJRwOx

In order to avoid the menu breaking onto 2+ lines, you'll want to trigger the Bootstrap menu to collapse sooner (i.e. turn into the mobile menu). This is because a side scrollable nav bar isn't good for user experience, and it causes styling issues.

Additionally, I see you have a `<div class="col-xs-12">` as a direct child of your `<ul class="header-navigator container">`. As far as I know, you shouldn't nest divs inside ul elements in HTML5, as some browsers may autoclose the parent ul element.

Hope this helps!